# Простой способ сформировать sqlite файл базы из MySQL

Tags: activerecord, sqlite, mysql, ruby-on-rails

В `rails` проекте используется `mysql` БД для хранение `active record` моделей.

Есть ли простой способ сформировать "копию" набора `active record` записей в `sqlite` базу?

Пока видеться, что надо пройтись по всем данным нужных моделей, и сформировать `sql`, который надо выполнить на коннекшене к `sqlite`.

Либо же, подготовить `sqlite` базу (путём вызова миграций на ней), а потом пройтись по всем объектам моделей из `Mysql` и делать `save`, но в `sqlite` базу. Хм. Я так понимаю, что достаточно понять как работать одновременно с двумя источниками данных для `active record`?

Comment: а сделать дамп

    mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE TABLE1 TABLE2 TABLE3 > /path/to/file/dump_table.sql

 а потом его в sqlite подгрузить?

да, возможно нужно будет файл дампа чуточку поправить.

Comment: @KoVadim, Хочется этот процесс автоматизировать, как перенести "руками" - масса вариантов. Хочется именно в идеологи active record & ruby.

Comment: @Чад

> Хочется именно в идеологи active record & ruby.

вести миграции?

Comment: @Etki - причём тут миграции? Прогон миграций можно использовать для формирования структуры sqlite базы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тихо сам с собою, я веду беседу... :-)

В итоге применил следующую схему:

```
work_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]

out_connection = {'adapter' => 'sqlite3',
            'database' => "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}.sqlite3"}
#здесь загружаем данные для копирования
model_data = SomeModel.all
#Переключаем на внешнюю базу
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(out_connection)
#Прогоняем миграции
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/migrate', nil)
#сохраняем данные
model_data.each do |obj|
  dst = SomeModel.new
  assign_values obj, dst
  dst.save!
end
#Переключаем обратно
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(work_connection)

...
def assign_values(src, dst)
  src.attributes.each do |name, val|
    dst.send "#{name}=".to_sym, val
  end
end
```